# XSD for JPA 2.0

Tags: java, jpa, xsd, persistence

A time ago XSD for JPA 2.0 could be found here http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd

But now this link is gone. The question is, where can I find this XSD?

Comment: What do you mean it isn't there ? it is for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that [JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads) contains different Java EE related XSDs in ./docs/schema folder.